# Grab map operator from service

Tags: angular, typescript, oop, rxjs, ngrx

This is a bit of a simple concept but it's flying over my head.

```
getHoleLng(id: number | string) {
return this.getHoles().pipe(
  map(holes => holes.find(hole => hole.id === +id).lng)
  );
}
```

I'm trying to grab this method from my service and I was wondering how I could grab it in my geolocation component?

```
Haversine(): void {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( x => {

      this.myLat = x.coords.latitude;
      this.myLng = x.coords.longitude;

      this.courseLat = this._mont.getHoleLat();
      this.courseLng = this._mont.getHoleLng();


    console.log(`longitude: ${ this.courseLat } | latitude: ${ this.courseLng }`);
    console.log(`longitude: ${ this.myLat } | latitude: ${ this.myLng }`);


    const myCoords: GeoCoord = {
      latitude: this.myLat,
      longitude: this.myLng
    };

    const dominos: GeoCoord = {
      latitude: this.courseLat,
      longitude: this.courseLng
        // latitude: this.courseLat,
        // longitude: this.courseLng
    };

    this.metres = this._haversine.getDistanceInMeters(myCoords, dominos);
    this.yards = this._haversine.getDistanceInYards(myCoords, dominos);
    this.kilometres = this._haversine.getDistanceInKilometers(myCoords, dominos);
    this.miles = this._haversine.getDistanceInMiles(myCoords, dominos);

    this.metres = this.metres.toFixed(2);
    this.yards = this.yards.toFixed(2);
    this.kilometres = this.kilometres.toFixed(2);
    this.miles = this.miles.toFixed(2);
 });
}
```

}

**Edit**

```
export class Hole {
  constructor(public id: number, public name: string, public lat: number, public lng: number) { }
}

const HOLES = [
   new Hole(1, 'Hole 1', 1234567, -12345324)
  ];
```

I'm trying to grab these coordinates!

Comment: what do you mean 'grab it' ? You want to execute this method in your main.ts ?

Comment: Exactly! I would like to get these. lat and. lng values

Comment: And did you try to do it ? What errors did you get? 
P.S: not telling you what to do, but this is pretty uncommon. Can't you import the function and execute it elsewhere?

Comment: `this.courseLat = this._mont.getHoleLat();`
`this.courseLng = this._mont.getHoleLng();`

Comment: The error I'm getting is "Expected 1 arguments, but got 0"

Comment: Well you're calling `this._mont.getHoleLat();` and it expects an id. The error is normal. you should call it like this `this._mont.getHoleLat(id)`;

Comment: Thanks for all the help @Mium! Could you take a look at the question again I've editied it

Comment: I posted an answer. Not sure it's what you expect. Tell me if it's what you wanted.

Comment: Can't thank you enough! the issue I'm running into now is where to define the id? The error I'm receiving in my console is "Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined"

Comment: Well that depends on what the id is. What does it correspond to ?

Comment: I've attached the code above

Comment: I updated my answer. please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import the service and inject it to your component.

In your `<name>.component.ts` : 
    import {YourService} from "servicePath";

```
export class NameComponent{
   // inject it here
   constructor(private yourService : YourService){
     // call it here (or elsewhere)
     this.yourService.getHoleLng(id).subscribe(...)
   }
}
```

or call it in your function :

```
Haversine(): void {
  // suppose for the example that id=1;
  let id = 1; // to be replaced by the wanted id

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( x => {

      this.myLat = x.coords.latitude;
      this.myLng = x.coords.longitude;

      forkJoin(
         this.yourService.getHoleLng.pipe(map( lng=> courseLng=lng)),
         this.yourService.getHoleLat.pipe(map( lng=> courseLng=lat))
      ).subscribe( ()=> {
           console.log(`longitude: ${ this.courseLat } | latitude: ${ this.courseLng }`);
            console.log(`longitude: ${ this.myLat } | latitude: ${ this.myLng }`);

         const myCoords: GeoCoord = {
           latitude: this.myLat,
           longitude: this.myLng
         };

         const dominos: GeoCoord = {
           latitude: this.courseLat,
           longitude: this.courseLng
           // latitude: this.courseLat,
           // longitude: this.courseLng
         };

         this.metres = this._haversine.getDistanceInMeters(myCoords, dominos);
         this.yards = this._haversine.getDistanceInYards(myCoords, dominos);
         this.kilometres = this._haversine.getDistanceInKilometers(myCoords, dominos);
         this.miles = this._haversine.getDistanceInMiles(myCoords, dominos);

         this.metres = this.metres.toFixed(2);
         this.yards = this.yards.toFixed(2);
      })    

}
```

The thing is you need to wait for both `lat` and `lng` coordinates to be returned by your services before proceeding to further processing. I used `forkJoin` operator to wait for both calls to be finished.

Comment: Much appreciated!